# ¿Cómo saber la cantidad de filas que tienen el checkbox habilitado en un JTable?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa para invitar a personas a eventos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla de la izquierda, están todos los invitados de mi base de datos, yo selecciono los que deseo invitar al evento.

La tabla de la derecha muestra todos los eventos de mi base de datos, solo debo seleccionar 1 solo.

Luego, al hacer clic en el botón Enviar Invitación, debo tener una forma de saber el ID de todos los invitados seleccionados en la primera tabla, y el ID del evento seleccionado en la segunda tabla para luego, guardar todo eso en mi base de datos y mostrar la invitación creada en la tabla inferior.

Código:

```
JButton btnEnviar = new JButton("Enviar Invitaci\u00F3n =>");
        btnEnviar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                // Tabla de Invitados
                tableInvitados.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent a) {
                        // Obtener la fila seleccionada
                        for (int i = 0; i < tableInvitados.getRowCount(); i++) {
                            Boolean checked = Boolean.valueOf(tableInvitados.getValueAt(i, 4).toString());
                            int fila = tableInvitados.rowAtPoint(a.getPoint());

                            if (checked) {
                                ArrayList<Integer> selection = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                                selection.add(fila);
                                System.out.println(fila);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Tabla de Eventos
                tableEventos.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                        int fila = tableEventos.rowAtPoint(arg0.getPoint());
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

No entiendo realmente cómo hacer todo esto.

1. ¿Cómo puedo guardar todos los ID de las filas que tengan el checkbox true?, con este ID, mas adelante podré enviar eso a la base de datos.
2. ¿Cómo hago lo mismo para la tabla Eventos?, saber el ID del evento seleccionado?.

¿Alguna idea?.

Comment: Los listener se van a activar cuando hagas click en la tabla. Eso es distinto de lo que has explicao. Tú quieres marcar casillas en una tabla y marcar una fila en otra y, al final, **cuando** pinches en un botón será cuando se cargue la información (se lee los que están marcados en las dos tablas y se envía la información). Ese código que es el que importa no lo has puesto. Por otra parte, si sólo quieres elegir un evento y no vas a modificar nada ¿No sería mejor usar un ComboBox que parece quedar más elegante?

Comment: @Awes0meM4n Tengo los dos addMouseListener de las tablas dentro del actionPerformed del botón. Podrías ayudarme a saber los invitados seleccionados con el checkbox y la fila seleccionada del evento?, es lo único que me falta para terminar el app.

Comment: Ahora mismo no puedo verlo en detalle. Sólo te diré que para ver los invitados uses el método getValueAt del modelo para ver si está marcado y entonces añadir el id con el mismo método. Para el evento terminaras antes con un combobox que metiendo a tratar la tabla

Comment: @Awes0meM4n he tratato de hacerlo, pero no me funciona, hasta ahora tengo esto: http://pastie.org/private/fi3pqmgae3p1dgddzmezq :( si desmarco una fila, debo remover esa fila del array, no me sale..

Comment: Lo que has hecho ya contesta a tu pregunta. No tienes que quitar nada, simplemente lanza ese código cuando pinches el botón de enviar invitación y usa un array nuevo donde cargues sólo los que están marcados

Comment: @Awes0meM4n a ver si me explico, el código que hice no me funciona. Me guarda el ID repetidas veces y no se como arreglarlo, tampoco se cómo borrar un ID si el usuario desmarca la casilla. Estoy perdido. Dame una mano a ver cuál es mi problema...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, borra los dos listener que no te sirven para nada y seguro que tendrás un lio de código que cada vez que se pincha la tabla te cargan ids y por eso se te repiten.

Para lo que pides lo que tienes que hacer es lo que te puse en los comentarios:

Creas un método para leer las filas con invitados:

```
private List<Integer> leerIDsInvitados(){
    List<Integer> invitados = new ArrayList<>();
    TableModel model = table.getModel();

    for(int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++){
        //Si la columna 4 está true añadimos el ID
        if((Boolean)model.getValueAt(i, 4) == true)
            invitados.add((Integer)model.getValueAt(i, 0));
    }

    //Esta fila es sólo para que veas que funciona
    System.out.println(invitados);

    return invitados;
}
```

En tu botón "Enviar invitación" pones que lance este método, recoges la lista con los ids y ya cargas en tu BD lo que necesites.

```
JButton btnEnviar = new JButton("Enviar Invitaci\u00F3n =>");
btnEnviar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        List<Integer> invitados = leerIDsInvitados();

        //Añades el código para leer el valor del combobox del evento
        //Que ya has tenido que hacerlo antes con el perfil de usuario
        //Y cargas tu BD o lo que tengas que hacer
    }   
});
```

Comment: gracias hermano. Una última cosa, tengo problemas para hacer lo mismo con evento, prefiero dejarlo sin checkbox para no complicarme más la vida, solo haciendo clic pero, no logro hacer que el procedimiento devuelva el int, cheka: http://pastie.org/private/cj4isw67gej31kf1qoltva

Comment: Yo aproveche [esta solución](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) que te genera una columna de botones. Creo que es una buena solución si sigues empeñado en usar una tabla para eventos. En este caso te sobraría el botón de enviar invitación.